# Magento 2 Min - max product attributes query

Tags: magento2

How do I filter using two separate product attributes?

Say I have two attributes assigned to products min-height and max-height and I want to use the URL query to return all the products contained in the limits but not the products where they intersect with these.

E.g. 
Inputs entered:
Min Height: 60 cm
Max Height: 80 cm

```
www.example.com/all-cats.html?min_height=60&max_height=80
```